# unconfirmed transaction bitcoin core

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

i have this problem two payments not go through  with bitcoin core 
Bitcoin Core version v0.11.2 (64-bit)

so what is going on ??

Status: 0/unconfirmed
Date: 6/12/2016 01:38
To: 1H9ZLnP6QiwQ7aZYETZ46S4vwQnBX1sGxB
Debit: -0.00380000 BTC
Net amount: -0.00380000 BTC
Transaction ID: de79ea7cf8b3c1b62e084c5f07bbd7853e081ffb021ec0039a8300a213deb798-000

Status: 0/unconfirmed
Date: 6/12/2016 18:33
To: 1BQZvu1bmHtmYEuZG7D5yUKfLRfvfZ8DJC
Debit: -0.01410100 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00001952 BTC
Net amount: -0.01412052 BTC
Transaction ID: 0a7c04048968a7216a09b636fcad69ce6ff2d40b93cb6d5f0adb60724fd08082-000
Merchant: bitpay.com

Comment: anyone could help with this ???

Comment: is this board for watching problems and not replaying to it =/

Comment: updated to v 0.12.0 still did not fix the issue , is anyone really understand how bitcoin core works out ??

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/llWmSmT.jpg

Comment: as photo shown , i don' t think this is a fee thing , something different going on

Answer (score 0):

Expect more delays until you start paying reasonable transaction fees. This site can help you:

https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

Comment: but i made other three transactions beside that one with a recommended fee and they are in the same situation removed from my balance and unconfirmed these one been 48 hours and other three were from 24 hours ago so i don't think its fees issue , i just need someone who understand this situation to help me out with this mess =/